# Why is this pointer valid when its object should be out of scope? (And some other weird behaviors)

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

I'm still new to c++ and have been studying object scope.
I've tested the code below and witnessed some weird behaviors.

```
struct Test
{
    int value, value2;
    Test() : value(1), value2(10) {};
};


Test* GetTestPointer() {
    Test t;
    t.value = 20;
    return &t;
}

int main() {
    Test* tp = GetTestPointer();
    int a = tp->value;
    int b = tp->value2;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20
10
```

I thought `Test t` would go out of scope so dereferencing its values in main would either throw an exception or an empty value. Why is it getting valid values as if the object is still alive?

Actually this is what I originally tried:

```
Test* tp = GetTestPointer();
cout << tp->value << endl;
cout << tp->value2 << endl;
```

Output:

```
20
18223279
```

Here `value2` is acting like it's invalid but I can get `value` just fine.
Conversely I tried reordering them:

```
Test* tp = GetTestPointer();
cout << tp->value2 << endl;
cout << tp->value << endl;
```

Output:

```
10
1459403656
```

Note that none of this happened when I properly initiated `tp` with `new`, as expected.

I know I would never write code like this in real life but I got really curious as to why any of this is happening.

1. When does `t` go out of scope in this case?
2. What does the ordering of `cout` have anything to do with what `tp` is dereferencing?
3. Why when I save them in buffers can I get the correct values?

Comment: You were lucky. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: _Why is this pointer valid_ - it isn't. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: What would an "empty" value look like?

Comment: I know when you begin it is hard to check whether your issue is not already explained somewhere else, but this is also much probable when you begin...make sure you question do not already exist before posting. Look for "undefined behaviour" as @tilz0R mentioned.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was sure this was already asked somewhere, unfortunately I could not find it because I wasn't aware this was an "undefined behavior" let alone how it quite works yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just got lucky to be correct value, but in general it is *undefined behavior* and your compiler should warn you about this.

Try to extend your example to something like this:

```
int my_sum(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
int main() {
    int res;
    Test* tp = GetTestPointer();
    res = my_sum(1, 2);
    int a = tp->value;
    int b = tp->value2;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You will see different output because your local scoped `Test` object was overwritten by another function call.

WHen you use `new` statement, then your object is not created locally, but on the HEAP memory and therefore it is valid when you go out of function scope. In this case, you have to use `delete`, to delete this object later.

Comment: More like unlucky I guess. I did get a warning that I was returning address of a temporary... but otherwise it compiled and ran just fine without any interruptions. Do undefined behaviors always go unnoticed like this? Dividing by zero for example would terminate my program.

Comment: You were unlucky because it may fail your program in the future :) But in general, undefined behavior can easily crash your execution :) @LinguistTroubadour